# Modeling a piece-wise objective function for a linear program

Tags: linear-programming, mathematical-modeling, operations-research

I am attempting to design a linear program where I optimize the amount of money I make by selling good $A$. Selling units of $A$ below a threshold $t$ results in an income of $a$ dollars per unit of $A$ and selling quantities greater than that threshold $t$ results in an income of $b$ dollars per unit.

How might I model this as a linear objective function?

The situation I'm trying to model is that every day I produce an expected amount of resource $A$ with the amounts known in advance. I can either choose to sell resource $A$ or store it for later selling, but I have a limited capacity of storage for the resource.

Comment: What is the relationship between $a$ and $b$?  That is, which one is bigger?

Comment: [Possibly related](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/5894)

Comment: As followup, I figured out that I could just split production of resource $A$ into two subresources, $A_{superior}$ and $A_{inferior}$ and just put a hard limit on the superior resource, but not the inferior and it worked out

Comment: @mooglin You can post an answer. It would by a helpful contribution to MSE.

Comment: How to model this depends on whether the $b$ dollars per unit applies to all units or just to the units in excess of $t$. It also depends on your answer to Rob's question (which of $a$ and $b$ is bigger).